# How do i set a Binding Value to a TargetNullValue property in a DataGridTextColumn WPF XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, entity-framework-6

i'm trying to put a default value on my DataGridTextColumn in case the Binding Property gives Null Value, like and if in sql server...

So i researched and found the property TargetNullValue where can i put a default value in case the column have a null.

But is not working as i am doing it. Throws me the next error

**System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: 'A 'Binding' cannot be set on the 'TargetNullValue' property of type 'Binding'. A 'Binding' can only be set on a DependencyProperty of a DependencyObject.'**

Here is a example of my XAML code.

```
<DataGrid x:Name="proveedorDataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" EnableRowVirtualization="True" ItemsSource="{Binding IsAsync=True}" Margin="15,50,25,70" RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected"
              SelectionMode="Single" IsReadOnly="True" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserResizeRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" PreviewKeyDown="ProveedorDataGrid_OnPreviewKeyDown">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="municipioColumn" Binding="{Binding Municipio, TargetNullValue={Binding CCodigoPostal.Municipio}}" Header="Municipio" Width="Auto" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

with the current resources

```
<Window.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="proveedorViewSource" d:DesignSource="{d:DesignInstance {x:Type Core:Proveedor}, CreateList=True}"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

Actually is binded with EntityFramework using DataSource...

Thank you so much in advance!

*Updated CLASS

```
public class Proveedor
{
    public Proveedor()
    {
        ValeVehiculoCombustibles = new HashSet<ValeVehiculoCombustible>();
        FacturaProveedors = new HashSet<FacturaProveedor>();
        EntradaBasculas = new HashSet<EntradaBascula>();
    }

    public Guid? Id_Proveedor { get; set; }

    public string Codigo { get; set; }

    public string RazonSocial { get; set; }

    public string Calle { get; set; }

    public string Colonia { get; set; }

    public virtual C_CodigoPostal CCodigoPostal { get; set; }
    public int CCodigoPostalId { get; set; }

    public string Telefonos { get; set; }

    public string RFC { get; set; }

    public virtual CuentaContable CuentaContable { get; set; }
    public Guid? CuentaContableId { get; set; }

    public short DiasCred { get; set; }

    public decimal SaldoMN { get; set; }

    public decimal AnticipoMN { get; set; }

    public decimal SaldoDlls { get; set; }

    public decimal AnticipoDlls { get; set; }

    public string Contacto { get; set; }

    public string Email { get; set; }

    public string Municipio { get; set; }

    public string Estado { get; set; }

    public string Ciudad { get; set; }

    public bool Estatus { get; set; }

    public DateTime Actualizado { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ValeVehiculoCombustible> ValeVehiculoCombustibles { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<FacturaProveedor> FacturaProveedors { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<EntradaBascula> EntradaBasculas { get; set; }
}
```

** And his configuration

```
public class ProveedorConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Proveedor>
{
    public ProveedorConfiguration()
    {
        ToTable("Proveedor");

        //PK
        HasKey(p => p.Id_Proveedor);

        Property(p => p.Id_Proveedor)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);

        Property(p => p.Codigo)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasColumnType("varchar")
            .HasMaxLength(6);
        HasIndex(p => p.Codigo)
            .IsUnique();

        Property(p => p.RazonSocial)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasColumnType("varchar")
            .HasMaxLength(60);

        Property(p => p.Calle)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasColumnType("varchar")
            .HasMaxLength(40);

        Property(p => p.Colonia)
            .HasColumnType("varchar")
            .HasMaxLength(30);

        Property(p => p.CCodigoPostalId)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasColumnType("int");

        Property(p => p.Telefonos)
            .HasColumnType("varchar")
            .HasMaxLength(30);

        Property(p => p.RFC)
            .HasColumnType("varchar")
            .HasMaxLength(13);
        HasIndex(p => p.RFC)
            .IsUnique();

        Property(p => p.CuentaContableId)
            .IsRequired();

        Property(p => p.DiasCred)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasColumnType("smallint");

        Property(p => p.SaldoMN)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasColumnType("decimal")
            .HasPrecision(10, 2);

        Property(p => p.AnticipoMN)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasColumnType("decimal")
            .HasPrecision(10, 2);

        Property(p => p.SaldoDlls)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasColumnType("decimal")
            .HasPrecision(8, 2);

        Property(p => p.AnticipoDlls)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasColumnType("decimal")
            .HasPrecision(8, 2);

        Property(p => p.Contacto)
            .HasColumnType("varchar")
            .HasMaxLength(60);

        Property(p => p.Email)
            .HasColumnType("varchar")
            .HasMaxLength(90);

        Property(p => p.Municipio)
            .HasColumnType("varchar")
            .HasMaxLength(50);

        Property(p => p.Estado)
            .HasColumnType("varchar")
            .HasMaxLength(31);

        Property(p => p.Ciudad)
            .HasColumnType("varchar")
            .HasMaxLength(45);

        Property(p => p.Estatus)
            .IsRequired();

        //Relationships
        //FK Proveedor -> ValeVehiculoCombustible
        HasMany(p => p.ValeVehiculoCombustibles)
            .WithOptional(v => v.Proveedor)
            .HasForeignKey(v => v.ProveedorId)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

        //PK Proveedor -> FacturaProveedor
        HasMany(p => p.FacturaProveedors)
            .WithRequired(f => f.Proveedor)
            .HasForeignKey(f => f.ProveedorId)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

        //FK Proveedor -> EntradaBasucla
        HasMany(p => p.EntradaBasculas)
            .WithRequired(e => e.Proveedor)
            .HasForeignKey(e => e.ProveedorId)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
    }
}
```

** And finally, here is the returned result of the query at debug mode...

[ViewSource Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jj6rd.png)

Comment: That’s not what TargetNullValue does or is supposed to do. What you need is a MultiBinding with a IMultiValueConverter that returns the first non-null value.

Comment: Thanks Dave M!

i understand the use of multibindings and purposes, but i don't know yet how to put them into my DataGrid with a CollectionViewSource.

Any recommendations?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't bind to `TargetNullValue`. You can only put a hard-coded value in there. If you want to bind, you can use a `DataGridTemplateColumn` with a `Textblock` and use a `DataTrigger` on it to change the value.

So, default the `Textblock` to bind to `Municipio`, then if it's `{x:Null}`, then bind it to `CCodigoPostal.Municipio`.

```
<DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Municipio}">
                     <TextBlock.Style>
                         <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                             <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding Path=Municipio}"></Setter>
                             <Style.Triggers>
                                 <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Municipio}" Value="{x:Null}">
                                     <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding Path=CCodigoPostal.Municipio}"></Setter>
                                  </DataTrigger>
                              </Style.Triggers>
                          </Style>
                      </TextBlock.Style>
                  </TextBlock>
              </DataTemplate>
          </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
      </DataGridTemplateColumn>
  </DataGrid.Columns>
```

If you want to go above and beyond (and do it right), you'd make a `DataTemplate` in your resources and just reference that instead of putting all the `xaml` right in-line.

If you want to use a resource, you would put the `DataTemplate` in your `Windows.Resources`.

```
 <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="template">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Municipio}">
                <TextBlock.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                        <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding Path=Municipio}"></Setter>
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Municipio}" Value="{x:Null}">
                                <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding Path=CCodigoPostal.Municipio}"></Setter>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </TextBlock.Style>
            </TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
```

Then, set the `CellTemplate`.

```
 <DataGrid x:Name="grid" Grid.Row="3">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn CellTemplate="{StaticResource template}">
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

Comment: Hi James!!
Thank you so much for your answer, i get the point of the DataTemplate and the triggers...

but i don't know how can i put them as a resource...

Btw, Using {Binding Path=Municipio} is not giving me any value, note that i'm using a CollectionViewSource to fill the DataGrid, so... i must reference it first to provide the data??

PD: i appreciate so much your time!.

Comment: @ReyHerrera I've updated my answer with how you'd use a ```DataTemplate```. Using a ```CollectionViewSource``` shouldn't matter.

Comment: James, thank you again!

Works like charm, but at some point i thinks it's no validating the x:Null value.

I've been using <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Municipio}" Value="{x:Null}">
                                <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding Path=CCodigoPostal.Municipio}"></Setter>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>

Comment: <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Municipio}" Value="{x:Static system:DBNull.Value}">
                                <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding Path=CCodigoPostal.Municipio}"></Setter>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>

Comment: <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Municipio}" Value="{x:Static system:String.Empty}">
                                <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding Path=CCodigoPostal.Municipio}"></Setter>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>

Comment: but is not changing the value at the end, i think that the trigger is not matching the null value returned from Sql Server.

Comment: @ReyHerrera What's type is ```Municipio```, and are you certain that the value is ```null```? If it's a ```string```, you may be running into the fact that it actually isn't ```null```. Instead, it will be an empty string.

Comment: Well, im pretty sure that my `sql server` table is returning a `null`, but i don't know how my `DataGrid` is taking the value, that's why i tried these triggers...
btw,`Municipio` is a `varchar` on `sql server` and a `string` in c# (`entity framework`.

Comment: @ReyHerrera Alright, well I think instead of checking for ```null```, you need to check for an empty string. So change ```{x:Null}``` to just empty quotes and see if that fixes it.

Comment: well, already tried, but still not working... but why? do i need to do a conversion?

Comment: @ReyHerrera Can you check the source data before you set the grid to check the actual value? A lot of times, when you're working with ```strings```, they won't be null. Instead they will just be empty.

Comment: James, thanks again and sorry to bother... but i debug it and it returns `null` value.

i think the issue is the trigger is not fired, because i made a validations with another string condition and is not working.. but why?

Comment: @ReyHerrera Alright. Change your binding back to the way I have in my answer, but add  ```OneWay``` to it. ```Binding="{Binding Path=Municipio, Mode=OneWay}"```. As long as you are using ```INotifyPropertyChanged``` in your class, it should work.

Comment: @ReyHerrera Can you post the class of the items that you're binding to?

Comment: @ReyHerrera Look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged?view=netframework-4.7.2). You need to incorporate ```INotifyPropertyChanged``` into your ```Proveedor``` class in order for your binding to get updates. That's the only thing I can think of.